# DateTime in entity Framework && DateTime in sql format returning different results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Guys i have a big problem in entity framework and DateTime. Here the problem:

First with entity:

When the user submit the form them those values are being create for a condicional query depending on which parameter the user type. Example:

```
var query =  from user in UserTable

select user;

        if(Request.Form["Category"])
        {
        query = query.where(add=>add.Category == Request.Form["Category"])
        }
       
//and here the between 
         if(Request.Form["start_date"] && Request.Form["end_date"])
        {
        query = query.where(add=>add.Date < Request.Form["start_date"] && add.Date > Request.Form["end_date"] )//equivalent to between
        }
    until...
    return query.ToList();
```

Good, but the problem remains that when the user wants to search by date, when converting the request form to datetime then the format are different from the input what was recived:

```
User'input
2003-12-02


Convert.ToDateTime
result : 02/11/2003(not iqual to the user input)
```

So, there is not coincidence(Well, thats what i guest because I read that entity solved this by itself). And i cannot set Date propery to String Because i cannot use between with a string.

Here the model simplified:

```
public string Category {get;set;}
public DateTime Date{get;set;}
```

But Thats not all

**Part 2**

I tried to query in  `02/11/2003` format to see if the query works and it did correctly, but when i tried with `2003-12-02`, here the results

```
 02/12/2003 format
16330 rows

2003-12-02 format
136 rows
```

Notice that they are the same but return different results. Moreover, when i check the results, i noticed that when querying in  `02/12/2003 format` the results include date lesser or highter:

Example:

```
Select date FROM Table WHERE date BETWEEN 02/12/2003 AND  03/12/2003

results include: 05/12/2003,30/12/2003
```

Why this significant diffents bettwen those two queries?

Comment: Not really an answer but when you are using `02/12/2003` this is translating to February 12th 2003, and `2003-12-02` is translating to December 2nd 2003. So it has to do with your date culture.

Comment: Upvoted up, You answered one of my question :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the culture of your database.  You can check your current culture by executing:

```
SELECT @@language
```

To see the date formats for your culture, execute:

```
EXEC sp_helplanguage
```

Based on that, you can `Convert.ToDateTime()` in C# with your specific culture like so:

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime endDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

// Set this to your culture if it's not en-US
DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;

try { startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["start_date"], usDtfi); }
catch {}

try { endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["end_date"], usDtfi); }
catch {}

if (startDate != DateTime.MinValue && endDate != DateTime.MaxValue)
{
    query = query.where(add=>add.Date <= endDate && add.Date >= startDate ) //equivalent to between
}
```

**Note that you had your dates backwards.  You have < startDate and > endDate.  Which is the opposite of `BETWEEN`.  (Unless you are considering startDate to be the larger of the 2 dates, which I am not.)**

Comment: When doing what you wrote, this is the result: Convert.ToDateTime("2012-09-11");//its returns 12/09/2012 12:00:00 a.m. But in the field of date, the format is 02-12-2012. How can I change the dateformat and with - and being in dateFormat to make the between statement? Remember that i cannot make a between with string and DateTime (DateTime > String)//error, cannot compare dataTime with string.

Comment: Did this answer it for you?

Comment: Yea, it did. Sorry for not voting up before :D